# merge 2 object by id

Tags: javascript, object

I want merge two object by id with java script, but i don't know how

```
var personData = {
    person1 : {
        uid: 112233,
        city: "esfahan",
        postalCode: 2345672345,
        phoneNumber: "03111234234",
        position: "ui designer"
    }}

var additionalPersonData = {
    person12: {
        uid: 112233,
        firstName: "reza",
        lastName: "hosseini"
    }}
```

> So that the output should look like:

```
result = [
 {
  uid: 112233,
  firstName: "reza",
  lastName: "hosseini"
  city: "isfahan",
  postalCode: 2345672345,
  phoneNumber: "03111234234",
  position: "ui designer"
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using  Object.assign():

```js
    var personData = {
    person1: {
        uid: 112233,
        city: "esfahan",
        postalCode: 2345672345,
        phoneNumber: "03111234234",
        position: "ui designer"
    }
    };

    var additionalPersonData = {
    person12: {
        uid: 112233,
        firstName: "reza",
        lastName: "hosseini"
    }
    };

    var result = [];

    result.push(Object.assign(
    {},
    personData.person1,
    additionalPersonData.person12
    ));

    console.log(result);
```

Comment: these object has many person but i write one of them

Comment: @MahdiPartovi then you have to use a loop or something, but in the example you are using different variable names, it is not possible to perform a loop using different variable names. Do you have an array  or something?